# Using Knockout ko template binding for google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, templates, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

i'm trying to use a knockout template to fill my google map marker info window with a click event to show wiki articles in a modal. right now, my markers are coming up blank i'm receiving no errors. any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

html snippet

```
<script type="text/html" id="info-template">

            <div data-bind="with: currentLocation">

               <div id="m-title" data-bind="text: title"></div>

            </div>

            <button id="wiki-a" data-bind="click: toggleWiki">

                Wikipedia Articles

            </button>

            <div id="pano"></div>

        </script>
```

js snippet

```
infowindow.setContent('<div id="info-window" data-bind="template:' + 
                        '{ name: \'info-template\'}"></div>');
```

full code at https://github.com/CHBaker/Neighborhood-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly add Knockout Js template inside the Google setContent method, the method specifically needs a string or html node to render.
See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

So the content you are adding will be added as string or html node. But in your case it seems to be string, as knockout template you are passing is not a valid DOM node, and will be treated as regular string. The key here is to render the html first and then get the content of it to set as infowindow.

Update your `infowindow.setContent` method with this

```
infowindow.setContent(document.getElementById("info-template").innerHTML);
```

Hope it Helps !

Comment: this is getting the html into the info window, but is this preventing the data bind click event within the template?

Comment: You can bind the event  `ko.applyBindings(<YourViewModel>, <your template node>)` after setContent Method

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but can I set that right in the next line after the setContent method? I should i set that at the bottom of my js file WITH the ko.applyBindings method i already have?

Comment: Yeah, you should call the method just after `setContent`, cause you want to set the binding of click event as soon as the popup is added. Adding at bottom of your Js will not work. Just a suggestion, as I looked into your codebase, you need to do major refactoring of code. I was not able to fix it for you, when I was looking for proper context. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: as far as adding the applyBindings method, i can't have two apply bindings methods. I'm struggling with this myself... looking for a fix where i don't have to refactor my whole codebase. anymore help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Just look at this post see if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970927/binding-knockoutjs-to-google-maps-infowindow-content